# How can I rename image while uploading and save name into mysql data and image file into directory?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, file-upload, rename

My code is working fine, I want to rename my image file name while uploading and save it. I have searched everywhere but it didn't help me (Maybe not enough or I am not sure what to Search for).

How could I change the name of my file to an Orignal File Name + Some unique Alpha-Numeric Words?

> Like: Orignal.jpg to Orignalabcd1234.jpg

And Also how could I remove spaces from Orignal Image File Name?

My code.php </>

```
$image=$_FILES['image']['name'];
if($image)
    {
    $image = stripslashes($_FILES['image']['name']);
    $image_extension = getExtension($release_artwork);
    $image_type = $_FILES['image_artwork']['type'];
    $image_size = $_FILES['image_artwork']['size'];
    $image_file_name="assets/images/".$image;
    copy($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $image_file_name);
    }
else
    {
    $image = '';
    }
```

I tried using this function [Link](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rename.php) but I can't save and store different images with the same file name

Comment: The filename is just a string. So if you want to remove the spaces from it, google how to remove spaces from a string using PHP. If you want to add extra stuff to the filename just concatenate it, like any other string. Then pass the modified string to the copy() command as the second argument.

Comment: P.S. If you're uploading a file, it's generally a better idea to use the `move_uploaded_file` command to save it permanently - this is a function which is specifically intended for this exact purpose. https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php

Comment: Also, why are you using stripslashes on the filename? What's the purpose of that? Is it a problem if the filename contains backslashes, for any reason?